# why linux can't catch C++ run-time errors such as uses a shallow copy constructor?

Tags: c++, linux

I'm studying on c++ copy constructor. I wrote the code that uses a shallow copy constructor that causes run-time errors for study. What I intended was making run-time error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class Person{ //define Person class                                                                  
  char *name;
  int id;
public:
  Person(int id, const char *name);//constructer                                                     
  ~Person();//distructer                                                                             
  Person(Person& p){
    this->name = p.name;
    this->id = p.id;
  }
  void changeName(const char *name);
  void show(){
    cout << id <<',' << name <<endl;
  }
};

Person::Person(int id, const char *name){
  this -> id = id;
  int len = strlen(name);
  this->name = new char[len+1];
  strcpy(this->name,name);
}
Person::~Person(){
  if(name)
    delete []name;
}

void Person::changeName(const char *name){
  if(strlen(name) > strlen(this->name))
    return;
  strcpy(this->name,name);
}

int main(){
  Person father(1,"Kitae");
  Person daughter(father);

  cout << "after object daughter maked ---" << endl;
  father.show();
  daughter.show();

  daughter.changeName("Grace");
  cout <<"daughter name changed ---"<<endl;
  father.show();
  daughter.show();

  return 0;
}
```

when I complied on windows 10(compiled by visual studio 2017) and run it, then it works well (run-time error occurs) but it doesn't work well on linux(compiled by g++ 7.3.0)(run-time error doesn't occurs). linux show no error occurs.

So, I debug that code on linux. I used gdb.

```
after object daughter maked ---
1,Kitae
1,Kitae
daughter name changed ---
1,Grace
1,Grace
[Inferior 1 (process 3297) exited normally]
```

Is it okay to use shallow copy constructor like that code? if it isn't, why windows and linux are show different result?

Comment: Double free causes Undefined Behavior. It is wrong to expect runtime error or anything particular to happen.

Comment: Also deleting something that wasn't allocated with the `new[]` keyword.

Comment: C++ does not work this way.  Unless you explicitly `throw` an exception, or you call a function that is documented to `throw`, you cannot expect anything to happen when undefined behavior is invoked.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: Bottom line -- you make a mistake like this, it's your responsibility to discover and fix these mistake.  There is no error handling, stack trace, etc. similar to Java or C# or some other language, that is guaranteed to "pop up" when you make these types of errors.

Comment: No need for `if (name) delete[] name`, just do `delete[] name`.

Comment: Bottom line: use `string`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shallow copy only causes the bug indirectly. What actually causes the error is that the pointer gets deleted twice, *because* of the shallow copy. And the error that happens because of a double-delete depends on the compiler and the operating system.

If you want to catch errors like that on linux, there's a really good tool called valgrind. Just run:

```
$ valgrind ./my_program
```

And it will tell you if there are any memory leaks or double-frees.

Or use the address sanitizer mentioned by another commenter when compiling your program. (It does make the code run slower, but that's ok for a debug build).

That being said, not all shallow copies are bad, and there are perfectly valid (and safe) use cases of a shallow copy constructor. For example, suppose I'm writing my own `shared_ptr` class. The implementation is pretty simple:

```
template<class T>
class shared_ptr {
    T* ptr;
    int* counter;
    void increment_counter() {
        int& count = *counter; 
        ++count; 
    }
    int decriment_counter() {
        int& count = *counter; 
        return --count; 
    }
   public:
    explicit shared_ptr(T* ptr) 
      : ptr(ptr)
      , counter(new int(1))
    {}
    // Make shallow copy, but increment the counter
    shared_ptr(shared_ptr const& other)
      : ptr(other.ptr)
      , counter(other.counter)
    {
        increment_counter(); 
    }
    ~shared_ptr() {
        int new_count = decriment_counter(); 
        // Only delete the pointer if this was the last copy
        if(new_count == 0) {
            delete ptr; 
            delete counter; 
        }
    }
};
```

Here, `shared_ptr` keeps track of how many instances of that pointer there are, and it only deletes the pointer if it was the last copy.

Answer (score 3):

By default, gcc doesn't try to detect run time errors caused by undefined behaviour. If you want this, there is a set of add-ons called sanitizers that can help you. Try `-fsanitize=address` or `-fsanitize=undefined` compiler flags.

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef6b3a68b098929a)